# Which version of the akka library is best?

Tags: osgi, actor, akka

I have just begun work with Akka with a view to using it within an OSGi container (apache-servicemix-4.4.1-fuse-06-03). Which version of Akka do people find best to use. At the time of writing there seem to be 3 choices:

- 1.3.1 - Out of date but seems to have camel and spring support.
- 2.0 - Latest stable release but no camel or spring support.
- 2.1-SNAPSHOT - Latest release, camel and spring support but only a snapshot release.

Thoughts?

Comment: Last one ;) You answered to your question!

Comment: Even though it's only a snapshot?

Comment: You decide, if you need camel & spring you have no choise. Snapshots usually become stable in time. If not, go for last stable version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you hold out for Akka 2.2.2 (push pineapple, shake the tree)